# Not enough whitespace in starred chat message due to tags

Tags: bug, design, chat, chat-stars, whitespace

Starred messages in chat don't have enough whitespace between lines, the problem is most visible if there are tags in the message. In the screenshot it can be seen that there isn't one pixel of space between the text in the second line and the tags in the first line:

[image: screenshots apparently bugged today]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 105.0.3 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2022.10.12.39069